# Only executing try statement if it is error-free

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I have a `try...catch` statement which is checking if it can assign a value to a property of an object, and then store it in local storage without exceeding the quota.

The issue I'm having here is that if it exceeds the quota, it still has assigned a new value to the property.

I'm not sure on how to tackle this problem. I have tried nesting try statements and using finally statements but I'm yet to figure it out.

```
let storageFiles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storageFiles')) || {};
const image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

try {
    // I need this block to only be executed if there's no error to catch
    // but I will still need to assign the value to the property before
    // saving it to local storage

    storageFiles.source = image.src;
    localStorage.setItem('storageFiles', JSON.stringify(storageFiles));
}
catch(err) {
    console.log('Local storage error: ' + err);
}
```

Essentially what I'm looking for is a way for me to only execute the code in the try statement if there is or will be no errors.

Is there a different approach I could take instead?

Comment: Don't you just want to unassign `storageFiles.source` in the `catch` block?

Comment: How can you know there won't be any errors if you don't run the code?

Comment: _"Only executing try statement if it is error-free"._ This is exactly for what try...catch is.

Comment: Executing the code without executing the code is the only way you can be sure that there will be no errors when you execute the code.

Comment: @kmgt Yes, but everything before the actual error in the try statement would be executed

Comment: @Oscar good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the [`Storage` interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-interface) that lets you check in advance that a storage operation will succeed. And there's nothing in JavaScript that lets you roll back the effects of code (like rolling back a database transaction). You'll have to run the code.

> The issue I'm having here is that if it exceeds the quota, it still has assigned a new value to the property.

I guess you mean the `source` property of the `storageFiles` object you've parsed.

At least two solutions come to mind:

1. You can keep the original and revert the change if it didn't save:

   ```
   let storageFiles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storageFiles')) || {};
   const image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
   const source = oldSource;
   try {
       storageFiles.source = image.src;
       localStorage.setItem('storageFiles', JSON.stringify(storageFiles));
   }
   catch(err) {
       storageFiles.source = oldSource;
       console.log('Local storage error: ' + err);
   }
   ```
2. Re-parse the object on failure:

   ```
   let storageFiles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storageFiles')) || {};
   const image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
   try {
       storageFiles.source = image.src;
       localStorage.setItem('storageFiles', JSON.stringify(storageFiles));
   }
   catch(err) {
       storageFiles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storageFiles')) || {};
       console.log('Local storage error: ' + err);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up using the second solution because it would work best in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take another approach.

You could first create a copy of what needs to be saved. Then try storing the copy and if that succeeds, assign the value to the original instance you'd be using further.